# Не работает roxterm

Tags: debian, terminal, gtk

Когда запускаю roxterm из терминала gnome на debian testing - в ответ получаю тонны строк вида:

> ** (roxterm:31715): WARNING **: VTE's inner-border property unavailable

и в конце - ошибка сегментирования. Странно то, что gnome терминал, основанный на vte вполне работает, более того, roxterm раньше работал без проблем.
В нем был настроен серый прозрачный фон, больше ничего особенного не было.

Проблемы начались вскоре после установки новой темы гном. Поставил flat - plat для GTK+ и sequoia-ng для gnome-shell. Для установки также потребовалось поставить пакеты из репов:

> albatross-gtk-theme blackbird-gtk-theme bluebird-gtk-theme greybird-gtk-theme gtk2-engines-murrine murrine-themes

Однако, их полное удаление, переключение на стандартную Adwaita и последующая перезагрузка не помогли.

Comment: у вновь созданного пользователя такие же проблемы?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да, таже ошибка. Создал пользователя `useradd -m -d /home/user user`
Перлогинлся, проверил, все темы - стандартные. Я, правда, не думаю, что ошибка связана сменой тем.

Comment: да, скорее всего «проблема» — в использовании тестируемых репозиториев. самое разумное, по-моему — отправить сообщение об ошибке. есть удобное и рекомендуемое средство для этого: [программа *reportbug* из одноимённого пакета](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting).

Comment: Отправил баг, хотя и немного странно, что не встретил ошибку больше нигде на форумах. Вроде, никаких особенных настроек нет.
На всякий случай ссылка
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=838586